# Have two websites on different server but need one database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want one website on one server and another website on another server, but only 1 database for both using php and mysql.
is it possible? if yes then how?

Comment: Either/both PHP instances can connect over the network the the MySQL server, assuming that they have access to do so.  It's incredibly straightforward.  Why don't you try it, then post a more specific question on [sf] if you have problems?

Comment: Can you not just point them to the same mysql database in your database connector class / database connection method using the appropriate IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. its possible. Normally you dont put your db on distant server. You should keep the db server on same data center so you avail high speed internal network link.

If your websites are in host `web1` and `web2` and database is in `dbhost1`, then in `web1` and `web2` connect to mysql with `dbhost1` as host name.

### mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("dbhost1", "user", "pass");
```

### PDO

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=dbhost1', "user", "pass");
```

### Legacy mysql extension

```
mysql_connect("dbhost1",  "user", "pass");
```

**Note:** Make sure in the database `user@web1` (on host `web1`) or `user@web2` (on host `web2`) has access.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to a remote database given the correct settings.

Failing that, you could write a service layer that could be called from both servers.

Answer (score 0):

while connecting to mysql database use same database connection credential on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not. But for security and performance issues i wouldn't do that.

The question is what do you understand under **on another server** is the server direct connected over LAN or is the server in another Data center. When the server is in another Data center you can get a lot of traffic and performance issues.

When the server is direkt connected you can change the my.cnf and change the line:

```
bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

then the server is reachable from outside. And you should give the user enough rights to connect from outside.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possibile.
you have to use a mysql server which is reachable from both servers. and you simply connect with the same host/user/pass from both servers:

```
define("WEBDOMAIN", "94.145.22.15"); //some fake data
define("DEFDBNAME", "my_db");
define("DEFUSERNAME", "my_user");
define("DEFDBPWD", "my_pass");

mysql_connect( WEBDOMAIN, DEFUSERNAME, DEFDBPWD );
mysql_select_db( DEFDBNAME);
```

That should be enaugh. You coud have some problems if your hosting providers doesn't allow servers to connect to external servers (sometimes ports are closed).

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons it is common, that You can't connect to a mysql server that has not authorized your hosting server. 
So in mysql, You have to allow a user to connect not only from localhost, but also from other host (if You have enought priviliges, You can do it from phpMyAdmin by editing user priviliges afair).